# Critical CSS won't load

Tags: css

I've tried to look into this in other threads and nothing has fixed my issue.

I built a site for my company on wordpress and everything worked and linked great. Yesterday we linked our domain to the new site and suddenly my CSS won't generate. I keep receiving an error that there's no stylesheet.

I've restored my site, I've disabled and reenabled plugins, cleared my site cache, and anything else I could find! Nothing has helped.

Could someone please help me in troubleshooting this issue? One other thing that happened with this switch suddenly shows my images as broken on one page only. The page not showing images is tinymile.ai/eats

My main site is tinymile.ai

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: WordPress does not typically need to generate CSS. Are you using a plugin/build process to generate critical CSS?

Comment: I do have Elementor which generates critical CSS, and then there's also Jetpack where I'm trying to regenerate the critical CSS but get the error saying there's no style sheet linked

Comment: When you say you "linked our domain" do you mean you went live and changed the URL? If so, did you do this using WP CLI or a migration plugin? If you changed the URL any other way, various serialized data in the database could have been corrupted and might be to blame for the styles and images breaking.

Comment: One other thing to check would be whether you have HTTPS enforced. That may have changed when you went live versus had it on a test site.